# Changing the color of a Text item from a FlatList onPress

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a category list that is being displayed using a FlatList I tried changing the color of a single item OnPress so the user gets a feed back of what item he selected,but all the items in the FlatList change color.

How do I go along about implementing something like this so that the only selected item changes color and gets the original color back when another item is selected

Here is a sample of the code used :

```
import colors from "../config/colors";
function Categories() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.Categories}>
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{}}
        data={category}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return <Text style={styles.Text}>{item.title}</Text>;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to maintain the selected item in a local state and have a selected flag for each item and switch the style according to the requirement.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  selectedText: {
    color: 'blue',
  },
  normalText: {
    color: 'black',
  },
});

function Categories(props) {
  const [categroy, updateCategory] = React.useState(props.category);

  const updateOnPress = (index) => {
    const categories = categroy.map((item) => {
      item.selected = false;
      return item;
    });
    categories[index].selected = true;
    updateCategory(categories);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.Categories}>
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{}}
        data={categroy}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => updateOnPress(index)}>
              <Text
                style={item.selected ? styles.selectedText : styles.normalText}>
                {item.title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can use the component like below

```
< Categories
      category={[
        { id: 1, title: 'aa' },
        { id: 2, title: 'bb' },
        { id: 3, title: 'cc' },
      ]}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [ selectedItem, setSelectedItem ] = useState();

const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <Pressable onPress={() => { setSelectedItem(item) }}>
            <View>
                <Text style={item === selectedItem ? styles.selectedText: styles.normalText}}>
    {item}</Text>
            </View>
        </Pressable>
    )
}
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  selectedText: {
    color: 'blue',
  },
  normalText: {
    color: 'black',
  },
});
```